# Как можно оптимизировать код в данной задаче? Не проходит по времени, использую алгоритм двух указателей

Tags: python, алгоритм

> Красотой строки назовем максимальное число идущих подряд одинаковых букв. (красота строки abcaabdddettq равна 3)
>
> Сделайте данную вам строку как можно более красивой, если вы можете сделать не более k операций замены символа.
>
> Формат ввода
> В первой строке записано одно целое число k (0 ≤ k ≤ 109)
>
> Во второй строке дана непустая строчка S (|S| ≤ 2 ⋅ 105). Строчка S состоит только из маленьких латинских букв.
>
> Формат вывода
> Выведите одно число — максимально возможную красоту строчки, которую можно получить.

```
 k = int(input())
s = str(input())
mass = list(set(s))
j = 0
for bukva in mass:
    left = 0
    right = 0
    count = 0
    while left != len(s) - 1:
        while right != len(s) - 1 and (s[right] == bukva or count != k):
            if s[right] != bukva:
                count += 1
            right += 1
        j = max(j, right - left)
        if s[left] != bukva:
            count -= 1
        left += 1
print(j)
```

Comment: Хочу уточнить, перед тем как попробовать решить данную задачу, операция замены это любой символ заменить на любой? т.е. допустим у нас  `jassssck` и если я проведу 4 замены получу `ssssssss` это имеется в виду? Просто если я прав то решение гораздо проще предложенных — вложенные циклы вряд ли нужны. Если это c кодварс скиньте пожалуйста ссылку, для тестов.

Comment: Думаю, что можно решить за *S log(A)*, где *A* - размер алфавита.

Comment: Ccылка на проверяющую систему https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/45468/problems/2/?success=84647744#30404/2017_04_25/J5lhC5hsbS

Comment: `на проверяющую систему ` Туда просто так не попадёшь

Comment: угу `У вас нет прав просматривать это соревнование`

Answer (score 1):

Попробую решить на C#

Итак, что вы делаете: вы начинаете слева и от него двигаете праввый указатель каждую итерацию Это значит, что при длине строки N вы в худшем случае выполните O(N**2) (N в степени 2) операций.

Квадратичный алгоритм конечно не очень эффективно. Но! у нас есть один хинт в задании - все символы - это английский алфавит в нижнем регисре. То есть, по сути, в строке 26 разных символов повторяются.

Таким образом, если вы решим задачу для одного сивола линейно, то запустив её 26 раз, у нас общая сложность остается линейной.

Пример, давайте пройдемся по символам и для каждого решим подзадачу

```
int MaxBeauty(string s, int k)
{
    int max = 0;
    for(char c='a'; c<='z'; c++){
        max = Math.Max(max, MaxBeauty(s, k, c));
    }
    return max;
}
```

Функию выше можно оптимизмровать, если заранее посчитать какие символы использованы в строке и только по ним пройтись. Оставим это как домашку.

Теперь решение для одного символа, которое тоже работает на 2 указателях, но при этом за линейное время.

```
int MaxBeauty(string s, int k, char c)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int nonMath = 0;
    
    int max = 0;
    
    while(left < s.Length)
    {
        while(right < s.Length && nonMath <= k)
        {
            if (s[right] != c)
            {
                nonMath++;
            }
            right++;
            
            if (nonMath > k)
            {
                nonMath--;
                right--;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        max = Math.Max(max, right - left);
        if (s[left] != c) nonMath--;
        left ++;
    }
    
    return max; 
}
```

Как видно из функции выше, я просто ищу максимальное окно в строке, где не-символов `c` не более, чем `k`.

Если бы вы поделились тестами своими, я бы их проверил, а так приходится самому придумывать =)

Проверка.

```
Console.WriteLine(MaxBeauty("aaabbbaaa", 2));
Console.WriteLine(MaxBeauty("aaabbbaaa", 3));
Console.WriteLine(MaxBeauty("aaababaaa", 2));
Console.WriteLine(MaxBeauty("baaababaaab", 2));
```

Вывод

```
5
9
9
9
```

---

**UPD**  Пример с небольшими улучшениями, просто отсекаем ненужные вычисления. Кардинально ничего не улучшает, просто небольшие оптимизации.

Например, имеет смысл начать с самых часто встречающихся букв, и если следующая буква даже с учетом замен не превысит максимум - нет смысла её обсчитывать.

```
int MaxBeauty(string s, int k)
{
    int max = 0;

    var counters = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if (counters.ContainsKey(c)) counters[c]++;
        else counters.Add(c, 1);
    }

    foreach (var kv in counters.OrderByDescending(z=>z.Value))
    {
        if (kv.Value + k < max) continue;
        max = Math.Max(max, MaxBeauty(s, k, kv.Key, max));
    }
    return max;
}
```

Ну и тут можно передавать текущий максимум и если уже никаких шансов его превысить.

```
int MaxBeauty(string s, int k, char c, int max)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int nonMath = 0;

    while (left < s.Length)
    {
        if (left + max > s.Length) return max;

        while (right < s.Length && nonMath <= k)
        {
            if (s[right] != c)
            {
                nonMath++;
            }

            right++;

            if (nonMath > k)
            {
                nonMath--;
                right--;
                break;
            }
        }

        max = Math.Max(max, right - left);
        if (s[left] != c) nonMath--;
        left++;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Попробовал ваше решение с двумя указателями.  На C#  думаю оно без проблем пройдет по времени, но на python не канает. Время выполнения программы сократилось на 50ms, но к нужному результату я так и не пришел. Мой изначальный алгоритм давал сложность не N^2, а скорее что-то близкое к линейной. За счет последнего цикла while. В исправленном алгоритме по вашей идее я использовал множество. Немного не понял с nonmath--, когда мы будем обновлять наш символ, у нас во внутренний while не зайдет, а  if (s[left] != c) nonMath--; должно загнать счетчик в отрицательные значения.

Comment: Изменил свой вопрос, теперь там алгоритм по вашей идее. Так же пробывал задавать строку из 26 букв алфавита и проходится по ней, но в данном тесте это только увеличило время исполнения, похоже из-за того, что различных букв меньше.

Comment: ссылка на проверяющую систему https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/45468/problems/2/?success=84647744#30404/2017_04_25/J5lhC5hsbS

Comment: у меня в алгоритме есть окное, определяемое левым и правым указателем длины (right-left), `nonMath` (он же `nonMatch` =)) - это число букв  в окне, отличных от той, с которой сейчас работаем. Когда двигаем правый край окна, мы как бы докидываем nonMath, когда левый - выкидываем, потому `--`. Отрицательным счетчик может стать, если правая граница не двинулась, а левая - двинулась, это выправится на следующей же итерации.

Comment: ваш алгоритм был квадратичный потому что в худшем случае левая граница двигалась бы только на 1 шаг, и на каждый шаг правая проходила бы от левой до конца строки. Это примерно (N**2)/2 итераций или квадратичная скорость.

Comment: Добавил парочку улучшений, хотя асимптотически то же самое остается.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант решения за линейное время (в общем случае`(n*Alphabet_Size)`), быстрый (~0.08 с для длины 100000):

```
def longestseqwithkrepl(s, k):
    n = len(s)
    cc = [0]*26
    cmax = 0
    left = 0
    right = -1
    mx = -1
    while right < n - 1:
        while right < n-1:
            right += 1
            ch = ord(s[right])-97
            cc[ch] += 1
            if cmax < cc[ch]:
                cmax = cc[ch]
            if right - left + 1 - cmax > k:
                break
            else:
                mx = max(mx, right - left + 1)

        while left < right:
            ch = ord(s[left])-97
            cc[ch] -= 1
            if cc[ch] + 1 == cmax:
                cmax = max(cc)
            left += 1
            if right - left + 1 - cmax <= k:
                break
    return mx
```

Старый вариант с Counter (медленнее):

```
from collections import Counter
k = 3
s = "acaaabbaaccaa"
n = len(s)
c = Counter()
left = 0
right = -1
mx = -1
while right < n - 1:
    while right < n-1:
        right += 1
        c[s[right]] += 1
        t = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
        if right - left + 1 - t > k:
            break
        else:
            mx = max(mx, right - left + 1)

    while left < right:
        c[s[left]] -= 1
        left += 1
        t = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
        if right - left + 1 - t <= k:
            break

print(mx)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я глянул, что там бинарная куча используется, и более подробно не интересовался, а там, наверное, каждый раз heapify? Я поленился свою косвенную кучу здесь  делать с обновлением полиций - кстати, редкая вещь, хотя у Седжвика описано, вроде как классика.

Comment: Да, а он линейный.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы меня навели на идею с кучей, которая умеет обновить любой свой элемент за логарифм. Думаю что можно сделать `n log(A)`. Заодно пополню мою коллекцию куч.

Comment: Ваш новый код в два раза быстрее и в пять раз проще всех упражнений с кучами. Круто!

Comment: Важная оптимизация - максимум относительно редко меняется. Получается что оптимизировать быстрый подсчёт максимума не выгодно. Выгодно его правильно закешировать. Как вы и сделали.

Answer (score 1):

***NB** Простое и самое быстрое решение ищите в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1508245/416121) [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo). Здесь вы найдёте другое решение, у которого лучшая асимптотика, но которое на практике в два раза медленнее. Константы рулят!*

Сложность решения в вопросе - `len(s) * len(set(s))`. Второй множитель не превосходит 26 - число букв латиницы. Хотя множитель не большой, из-за него Питону не хватает времени. Для ускорения пригодится счётчик со следующим интерфейсом:

> ```
> Counter()          # создать пустой счётчик;
> Counter.inc(c)     # увеличить на единицу счётчик для символа c;
> Counter.dec(c)     # уменьшить на единицу счётчик для символа c;
> Counter.get_max()  # вернуть значение максимального счётчика.
> ```

Со счётчиком решение задачи выглядит так:

```
def beauties(k, s):
    c = Counter()
    i = 0
    for j, v in enumerate(s):
        c.inc(v)
        while k + c.get_max() < j - i + 1:
            c.dec(s[i])
            i += 1
        yield j - i + 1
```

Это генератор, который для каждой позиции `j` возвращает максимальную длину `k`-красивой строки с концом в `j`.  Из всех длин надо выбрать максимум.

`Counter` устроен как [куча (пирамида)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0). Рядом с собственно кучей хранится словарь указывающий положения символов в куче. Куча и словарь меняются согласованно. Нулевые счётчики из кучи исключаются.

Сложность операции `c.get_max` - константная, операций `c.inc`, `c.dec` - логарифмическая от объёма счётчика (26 символов). В худшем случае требуется пять операций, в среднем меньше одной - чаще всего порядок элементов в куче не меняется. Сложность алгоритма в целом - `len(s) * log(len(set(s)))`. В сравнении с оригинальным алгоритмом второй множитель попал под логарифм.

Всё вместе:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._heap = []
        self._index = {}

    def inc(self, key):
        if key in self._index:
            i = self._index[key]
        else:
            i = len(self._heap)
            self._index[key] = i
            self._heap.append([0, key])
        self._heap[i][0] += 1
        self._sift_up(i)

    def dec(self, key):
        i = self._index[key]
        if self._heap[i][0] > 1:
            self._heap[i][0] -= 1
            self._sift_down(i)
        else:
            j = len(self._heap) - 1
            assert self._heap[i][0] <= self._heap[j][0]
            self._swap(i, j)
            self._heap.pop()
            del self._index[key]
            if i < len(self._heap):
                self._sift_up(i)

    def get_max(self):
        return self._heap[0][0]

    def _swap(self, i, j):
        self._heap[i], self._heap[j] = self._heap[j], self._heap[i]
        self._index[self._heap[j][1]] = j
        self._index[self._heap[i][1]] = i

    def _sift_up(self, i):
        while i > 0:
            j = (i - 1) // 2  # parent
            if self._heap[j][0] >= self._heap[i][0]:
                break
            self._swap(j, i)
            i = j

    def _sift_down(self, i):
        while True:
            k = i  # greatest value index
            j = 2 * i + 1  # left child
            if j < len(self._heap) and self._heap[k][0] < self._heap[j][0]:
                k = j
            j += 1  # right child
            if j < len(self._heap) and self._heap[k][0] < self._heap[j][0]:
                k = j
            if k == i:
                break
            self._swap(i, k)
            i = k


def beauties(k, s):
    c = Counter()
    i = 0
    for j, v in enumerate(s):
        c.inc(v)
        while k + c.get_max() < j - i + 1:
            c.dec(s[i])
            i += 1
        yield j - i + 1


print(max(beauties(int(input()), input()), default=0))
```

На больших примерах куча быстрее перебора символов в пятнадцать раз. Возможно, этого хватит - проверить я не могу.

Comment: Хорошо получилось.(только непорядок, что имя Counter пересекается с collections)

Comment: Мой код с Counter вдвое медленнее этого, а попробовал  сермяжный список с модификацией максимума -  втрое быстрее получается (понятно, что пока алфавит невелик)